# Handling Multiple Correlation IDs in Load Runner

Tags: scripting, performance-testing, load-testing, correlation, loadrunner

I am a beginner in Load Runner V 11.50. I was scripting a login page and then logout under Action. I applied the correlation from Design Studio. But the problem is, a single ID value is applied to all requests having the ID as parameter. In reality, the ID value generated from 1 request is passed in other and from the later request another ID value is getting generated in passed in rest all requests. So the replay status is failed. I guess multiple correlation is required in this case. Anyone can suggest anything on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are likely referring to is a state variable, which is generated on page A and passed back on page A+1.   You will need to handle this with manual correlation.

Automation in correlation is not meant to replace manual correlation, only to improve the efficiency of the developer when the pattern is well known.  In this case because of the constantly changing nature of when a value is populated and used you will need to address this manually.

As you are a beginner, this is an opportunity for your mentor to reground the material from your classroom training and work with you to reinforce your manual correlation processes and skills.  If you are being asked to perform without a mentor then your management is setting you up to fail as a new person in this field.

Here is a podcast which should help you on the identification front for manual correlation.

http://www.perfbytes.com/dynamic-data-correlation

Comment: Thanks @James Pulley. Yes, I am a beginner and the application I have got needs manual correlation. Thank you for your timely help.

Answer (score 1):

Please put web_reg_save_param before each request which is generating dynamic value in this case.
**Example:**

```
 web_reg_save_param("param1")
    A
    web_reg_save_param("param2")
    B --> Pass {param1} in B
    web_reg_save_param("param3")
    C --> Pass {param2} in C
and so on...
```

Also learn capturing various LB/RB,escape sequences,Arguments in correlation etc.

Comment: Yes @dimyo I have to learn manual correlation. Here in this case tokens are getting generated in below format. Request 1--  token1 Generated, then request 2--  token1 passed as parameter value & token2 Generated, request 3-- token2 passed as parameter value. How to handle this case in manual correlation? Please help as I am a fresher.

Comment: Try to go thru with this http://motevich.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/loadrunner-webregsaveparam-boundaries.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try using auto correlation function of load runner for now. But this will not work in all cases. Any how uou need to learn manual correlation methods.

This article will be helpful:http://www.guru99.com/correlation-in-loadrunner-ultimate-guide.html

First you need to practice manual correlation from Generation logs. later on after experience correlations can be done from Tree view.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Do not use auto correlation unless you are fully skilled in manual correlation.  Doing so will likely result in a failure that you are unable to address and will result in a chorus of "blame the tool" when the real issue is the user of the tool